# Canvas shown in the wrong way in Inspector in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApYAz.png)

This is how my canvas components shown in Inspector. It seems that i'm using a different version of canvas from those used in videos online. I've been searching online for how to make UI in Unity but I found their canvas looks different.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISw7D.png)

that's how it looks.

I tried creating new UI object in different locations in the hierarchy but I can only create the first one. I started a new project then did the same thing and it went corret(the right version was shown). I also tried to copy the canvas object from the second project into the first project as a Prefab, however even it is the exact same GameObject it looks different (the wrong version was shown) in Inspector in my first project. I can't figure out what happened... could there be something wrong with the project itself? or pakages imported?

And beside this issue, I found everying(like canvas scaler/Rect transform shown in the wrong way under the wrong canvas).

how can I fix this?

Comment: You're not using the wrong version, but you're viewing the `Inspector` in `Debug` mode. Using the three dots in the top right corner of the `Inspector` window, you can change the view back to normal. You can find more info about the Inspector Options in the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/InspectorOptions.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. This problem was bothering me for days. Problem resolved now. I'm a idiot!